# how to update empty datatable by the data from another datatable

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have 2 servers that contain the same databases with the same structure (Main Server + Sub Server).

1. I deleted all data from the table in the sub server.
2. I got the data from the table from the main server and put it in Datatable.
3. I copied the data from the Datatable of the server2.
4. I use Dataadapter2 to update the table in the sub server.

but still, the sub server is empty?!

```
'Delete Data From The Sub Server
    xSlConn.Open()
    Dim xcmddelete As New MySqlCommand("Delete FROM tblplaces", xSlConn)
    xcmddelete.ExecuteNonQuery()


    'Get Data Drom The Main Server
    Conn.Open()
    Dim xcmd1 As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblplaces", Conn)
    Dim xdt1 As New DataTable
    Dim xda1 As New MySqlDataAdapter(xcmd1)
    xda1.Fill(xdt1)



    'Preparing the datatable for the Sub Server
    Dim xcmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblplaces", xSlConn)
    Dim xdt2 As New DataTable
    Dim xda2 As New MySqlCommand(xcmd)
    Dim xB As New MySqlCommandBuilder(xda2)
    xda2.Fill(xdt2)

    'Copt the data from the main datatable to the sub datatable
    xdt2 = xdt1.Copy()

    'Update The Datatable2
    xB.GetUpdateCommand()
    xda2.Update(xdt2)
```

Comment: I'm sure you're going to get some solutions to the problem, but what exactly is the end goal of your two databases?  Is Sub supposed to be a replica of Main maybe?  If so there are probably a number of different paths to go down before trying to build your own replication system

Comment: @Hursey I wanted to have server database and local database, I will use the local to make quick reports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `xda2.Fill(xdt2)`

This line of code is useless; the next line of code tosses out xdt2 anyway

> `xdt2 = xdt1.Copy()`

This line duplicates the datatable. It *won't* set all the rows in `xdt2` to be `RowState` of `Added`, which is what the datadapter needs them to be in order to run an insert on them

A dataadapter inspects each row's RowState. `Unchanged` rows are ignored. `Added` have the INSERT command run on them, `Modified` maps to UPDATE, `Deleted` maps to the DELETE query

Right now all the rows in your xdt1 are `Unchanged` because the dataadapter called `AcceptChanges` on them after it added them to the table

---

Now.. you don't need to copy the data at all; you can just set all the rows in xdt1 to be Added so the xdt2 adapter will use its INSERT command on them.  Also, it should be possible to just swap the connection out on the insertcommand

```
'Get Data Drom The Main Server
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblplaces", Conn)
da.Fill(dt)
Dim xB As New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
da.InsertCommand.Connection = xSlConn

For Each ro as DataRow in xdt1.Rows
  ro.SetAdded()
Next ro
da.Update(dt)
```

---

Or, you can simply request that the `xda1` adapter NOT call AcceptChanges on them at all, so they will be in Added state already:

```
'Get Data Drom The Main Server
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblplaces", Conn)
da.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False
da.Fill(dt)
Dim xB As New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
da.InsertCommand.Connection = xSlConn
da.Update(dt)
```

Or if you're pushing to a different db

```
'Get Data Drom The Main Server
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblplaces", Conn)
da.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False
da.Fill(dt)

Dim da2 as New SqliteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblplaces", "put a connection string here")
Dim xB As New SqliteCommandBuilder(da2)
da2.Update(dt)
```

Note; this latter example uses eg SQLite as a demo of declaring two different adapters of different types for different db - it doesn't guarantee that eg the specific SQLite library you're using actually contains a dataadapter implementation (some don't)

Comment: thanks but what if the second datatabse is SQLite?

Comment: Same idea, just use two different dataadapters - blend your code and mine. I only reduced it to one because you said they were the same db. Read the rest of the advice again, about how dataadapters know a row is new and INSERT it, and then fix up your code - one datatable, no acceptchangesduringfill, two dataadapters one for MySQL, one for SQLite. Don't copy the datatable

Comment: thanks, I added another dataadapter but I got an error (Object reference not set to an instance of an object), could you please edit the code above

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to make `New` - `Dim da as MySqlDataAdapter` `da.Fill(..)` will explode because the da variable isn't set to any object - it's Nothing

Comment: 'Get Data Drom The Main Server
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblplaces", Conn)
        Dim da1 As New SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblplaces", xSlConn)
        da.AcceptChangesDuringFill = False
        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim xB As New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
        da1.InsertCommand.Connection = xSlConn
        da1.Update(dt)

Comment: Think about it; you make a MySqlCommandBuilder which adds an insertcomnand into `da` but you're not trying to insert into the mysqldb... and because your sqlite da1 has never had an InsertCommand generated for it, it's Nothing. Your da doesn't need commands building because it's selecting only. Your sqlite da1 is the one that needs the insert command. It doesn't need its connection string altering

Comment: sorry but I got the same error, I added DataAdapter as an instance object and fill it with another data table, but the same error

Comment: I'm not sure you're thinking carefully about the code you're writing - NullReferenceException is very common and easy to diagnose; you're trying to use something that is Nothing. Use the debugger to find out *what* is Nothing and then use your deductive reasoning to workout *why* it is Nothing, and *what* something you need to set it to so things can work

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use `Using...End Using` blocks to make sure you database objects are disposed. Don't declare database connections and commands outside of the method where they are used.

Your main problem is the `Fill` method of the `DataAdapter` sets all rows to unchanged. I changed this to the `DataTable.Load` method which takes a parameter of `LoadOption`. This will preserve the `RowState` `Added`. Then when you call `Update` on the `DataAdapter` the row will be recognized. If the row is `Unchanged` the `DataAdapter` will not update the database.

```
Private ConStrMain As String = "Your Main server connection string"
Private ConStrSub As String = "Your Sub server connection string"


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Delete Data From The Sub Server
    Using conSub As New MySqlConnection(ConStrSub),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand("Delete FROM tblplaces", conSub)
        conSub.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    'Retrieve data from Main server
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using conMain As New MySqlConnection(ConStrMain),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblplaces", conMain)
        conMain.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader, LoadOption.Upsert)
        End Using
    End Using
    'Insert data from Main to Sub server
    Using conSub As New MySqlConnection(ConStrSub),
            da As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblplaces", conSub)
        Dim sb As New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
        da.Update(dt)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: *I changed this to the DataTable.Load method* - Not necessary - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.acceptchangesduringfill?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0

Comment: @CaiusJard I see that you set that property in your answer. Just a slightly different approach.